# JMSSecurity exception while trying to subscribe to ActiveMQ Artemis ManagementNotifications

Tags: spring-boot, jndi, activemq-artemis

I'm using Spring Boot to perform a `JNDI lookup` so I can subscribe to Artemis' management notifications and figure out when a client is no longer subscribed to a particular topic. I'm fairly new to JNDI  and my understanding is that the code snippet I've provided causes a connection to an existing Artemis broker to be established and consequently captures notifications being sent by the broker.

I get an error when control hits the `connection = cf.createConnection();` line in the code snippet provided.

Error:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /ip:port. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
...
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /ip:port. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

How do I include the username, password, keystore and truststore in the `InitialContext` so that this error doesn't show up?

Code I'm using:

```java
@ComponentScan({"com.management.notifications"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ManagementNotificationTestApplication {

    @Value("${JMS_BROKER_TRUSTSTORE}")
    private String pathToTrustStore;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ManagementNotificationTestApplication.class);
    }


    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomething() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        Connection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
            properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://ipAddress:portNumber?&" + "sslEnabled=true&" +
                    "trustStorePath=" + pathToTrustStore + "&trustStorePassword=" + "abc");

            // Step 1. Create an initial context to perform the JNDI lookup.
            initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);

            // Step 3. Perform a lookup on the Connection Factory
            ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

            // Step 4.Create a JMS connection, a session and a producer for the queue
            connection = cf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Step 5. Perform a lookup on the notifications topic
            Topic notificationsTopic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/notificationsTopic");

            // Step 6. Create a JMS message consumer for the notification queue and set its message listener
            // It will display all the properties of the JMS Message
            MessageConsumer notificationConsumer = session.createConsumer(notificationsTopic);
            notificationConsumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(final Message notif) {
                    System.out.println("------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Received notification:");
                    try {
                        Enumeration propertyNames = notif.getPropertyNames();
                        while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                            String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
                            System.out.format("  %s: %s%n", propertyName, notif.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
                        }
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                    }
                    System.out.println("------------------------");
                }
            });

            // Step 7. Start the Connection to allow the consumers to receive messages
            connection.start();

            // Step 10. Try to create a connection with unknown user
            try {
                cf.createConnection("not.a.valid.user", "not.a.valid.password");
            } catch (JMSException e) {
            }

            // sleep a little bit to be sure to receive the notification for the security
            // authentication violation before leaving the example
            /*Thread.sleep(2000);*/
        } finally {
            // Step 11. Be sure to close the resources!
            if (initialContext != null) {
                initialContext.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be configuring all this on the ConnectionFactory on the server from which you are getting it via JNDI

Comment: Do you mean the Artemis broker must have all this configured? If so, then yes, the username, password and relevant certificates have already been configured, and other clients are able to connect to the broker. The issue is just with this JNDI stuff.

Comment: Can you share the login.config file of ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: @ehsavoie, he's using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` which is a client-side only JNDI implementation. There's nothing to configure here on the server. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#jndi) for more details on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your JNDI code. You just need to pass the username and password via [`createConnection(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). This is standard practice in JMS.

It's worth noting that the fact that you're getting an authentication error means that your SSL configuration is working. If your SSL config wasn't correct then you'd get an SSL error before you even made a successful connection to the broker and tried to authenticate.